# Google AdSense below article in MediaWiki

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, adsense

I wonder how I can put a unit of Google AdSense under the article inside the border.  That is:

```
   Name Article
   .
   .
   .
   end

   Category

                         box adsense
```

I only found a MediaWiki extension for using AdSense in the sidebar. I am using the Vector skin.

How can I do this?
(Ps. I'm in the early stages of web programming :-) )

Comment: I copyedited your post a bit.  I assume the AdSense extension you found was [this one](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_AdSense_2)?

Comment: correct, the extension is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to modify the existing AdSense extension to inject the ads in a different location; this will probably require changing it to use a different hook, since the one it's using seems to be sidebar-specific.

Alternatively, a crude but effective way is to edit the [skins/Vector.php](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/skins/Vector.php?view=markup) file (or the corresponding file for whichever skin(s) you're using) in your MediaWiki installation and add the AdSense code there, as if you were adding it to an ordinary HTML web page.  (Presumably you'd want to put it somewhere near the end of the bodyContent div; look for a line that says `<!-- /bodyContent -->`.)  The disadvantage of this method is that you'll probably have to redo it whenever you upgrade MediaWiki.